# SQL Server: Average counts by hour and day of week

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, group-by

#### Background

I have a table set up in a SQL Server environment that contains a log of various activity that I'm tracking.  Particular log items use unique codes to categorize what activity is taking place and a datetime field tracks when that activity occurred.

#### Problem

I would like to, using either a single query or a stored procedure, get an average of hourly counts of activity, grouped by day of the week.  Example:

```
Day      | Hour | Average Count
-------------------------------
Monday   | 8    | 5
Monday   | 9    | 5
Monday   | 10   | 9
...
Tuesday  | 8    | 4
Tuesday  | 9    | 3
...etc
```

Right now I've got a query setup that spits out the counts per hour per day, but my problem is taking it a step further and getting average by day of week.  Here's my current query:

```
SELECT CAST([time] AS date) AS ForDate,
   DATEPART(hour, [time]) AS OnHour,
   COUNT(*) AS Totals
FROM [log] WHERE [code] = 'tib_imp.8'
GROUP BY CAST(time AS date),
   DATEPART(hour,[time])
   ORDER BY ForDate Asc, OnHour Asc
```

Any suggestions as to how I might accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just group by [weekday](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx).

Comment: Will that average the counts though?

Comment: No, if you want to average a count then you'll have to first run a count and then run an average on the results: `select field, avg(countField) from ( select field, count(*) as countField group by field) result group by field`

Comment: If you provide some source data (e.g. how you got to 5) we'll have a better idea exactly how you want to obtain totals, averages, or averages of totals. The word problem is a little ambiguous and without source data it's hard to determine where 5,5,9 etc. come from.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Guessing here:

```
SELECT [Day], [Hour], [DayN], AVG(Totals) AS [Avg]
FROM
  (
        SELECT 
          [Day]  = DATENAME(WEEKDAY, [time]),
          [DayN] = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [time]),
          [Hour] = DATEPART(HOUR,    [time]),
          Totals = COUNT(*)
        FROM dbo.[log] 
            WHERE [code] = 'tib_imp.8'
        GROUP BY 
          DATENAME(WEEKDAY, [time]),
          DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [time]),
          DATEPART(HOUR,    [time])
  ) AS q
GROUP BY [Day], [Hour], [DayN]
ORDER BY DayN;
```

Again, without data, I might once again be throwing a handful of mud at the wall and hoping it sticks, but perhaps what you need is:

```
SELECT [Day], [Hour], [DayN], AVG(Totals) AS [Avg]
FROM
(
    SELECT 
  w = DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, [time]),
      [Day]  = DATENAME(WEEKDAY, [time]),
      [DayN] = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [time]),
      [Hour] = DATEPART(HOUR,    [time]),
      Totals = COUNT(*)
    FROM dbo.[log] 
      WHERE [code] = 'tib_imp.8'
    GROUP BY 
  DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, [time]),
      DATENAME(WEEKDAY, [time]),
      DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [time]),
      DATEPART(HOUR,    [time])
  ) AS q
GROUP BY [Day], [Hour], [DayN]
ORDER BY DayN;
```

This is also going to produce integer-based averages, so you may want to cast the Totals alias on the inner query to DECIMAL(something,something).

Comment: @Siva you're right. I originally only had the first two, then added the outer while testing, and didn't ultimately need it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Simple and elegant.  Great answer, worked as expected.  Sorry for not providing the original data, there was a lot of it (and the numbers I posted in my question were fake - as I had not yet achieved the averaging.  But ultimately, the data could be any random set of log entries at random time / days over the past few weeks...  If that makes sense.  Anyhow - thank you very much!

Comment: @AaronBertrand I thought we had it (but then a week later it turns out that it's not the case)...  There is actually no difference between the inner and outer statements as far as what they return.  The outer inner query is already grouped by day of the week - and therefore returns only one value / hour of day / day of week (regardless if we are examining multiple weeks).  So the outer query simply averages a single number, which will always be the same as the single count... does that make sense?

Comment: @mbeasley as written, no. Please supply some sample data and desired results. I can't solve a word problem in T-SQL, and like I said above, I am guessing. I can, however, solve a data problem. I asked for this Apr. 26 in a comment to the question. If you provide what I asked for, I'll have a much better chance to provide the query that you need. If the problem has changed, perhaps it is worthy of a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
; WITH a AS (
    SELECT CAST([time] AS date) AS ForDate
       , DATEPART(hour, [time]) AS OnHour
       , txtW=DATENAME(WEEKDAY,[time])
       , intW=DATEPART(WEEKDAY,[time])
       , Totals=COUNT(*)
    FROM [log] WHERE [code] = 'tib_imp.8'
    GROUP BY CAST(time AS date)
    , DATENAME(WEEKDAY,[time])
    , DATEPART(WEEKDAY,[time])
    , DATEPART(hour,[time])
)
SELECT [Day]=txtW
, [Hour]=OnHour
, [Average Count]=AVG(Totals)
FROM a
GROUP BY txtW, intW, OnHour
ORDER BY intW, OnHour
```

Comment: John, even though your execution plan has an additional sort operator compared to the other two solutions here, the output does not seem to order correctly (the days seem to be ordered randomly).

Comment: Does the ORDER BY fix the result?

Comment: No, now it orders by weekday name alphabetically (Friday, Monday, Thursday, Tuesday, Saturday, Sunday, Wednesday).

Comment: There, that sorts as desired. But the extra sort still makes the plan more expensive than the other two solutions (which have identical plans).

Comment: Maybe putting the function calls into the cte helps

Comment: That is more equivalent. However please check your syntax - you reference `ForDate` multiple times, but this is an alias you created in the `SELECT` so you can't reference that. You are also missing a comma before the last `GROUP BY` column inside the CTE.

Comment: thx, was editing from an iPad, which doesn't always work out:/ Back to PC now.

Comment: Nice. I have the same problem. PS the casts to DATE aren't necessary.