# Average Counts by Hour by Day of Week

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, group-by

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326036/sql-server-average-counts-by-hour-and-day-of-week) helped get me part of the way there:

```
SELECT 
    [Day], 
    [Hour], 
    [DayN], 
    AVG(Totals) AS [Avg]
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        w = DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, ForDateTime),
        [Day]  = DATENAME(WEEKDAY, ForDateTime),
        [DayN] = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, ForDateTime),
        [Hour] = DATEPART(HOUR,    ForDateTime),
        Totals = COUNT(*)
    FROM 
        #Visit
    GROUP BY 
        DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, ForDateTime),
        DATENAME(WEEKDAY, ForDateTime),
        DATEPART(WEEKDAY, ForDateTime),
        DATEPART(HOUR,    ForDateTime)
) AS q
GROUP BY 
    [Day], 
    [Hour], 
    [DayN]
ORDER BY 
    DayN;
```

How could this be changed so rather than showing the average by Hour, e.g. 9, 10, 11, 12, etc. It shows it by 09:30-10:30,10:30-11:30,11:30-12:30,12:30-13:30 all the way up to 23:30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach is to offset `ForDateTime` by 30 minutes. Basically you just need to replace *every* occurence of `ForDateTime` with `dateadd(minute, 30, ForDateTime)` in the query.

In the resultset, `Hour` `9` gives you the timeslot from 8:30 to 9:30, and so on.

Comment: Thanks @GMB, how would you suggest handling the resultset in terms of showing 09:30-10:30 rather than 9 ?

Comment: @Philip: string concatenation maybe? `CONCAT([Hour], ':30-', [Hour] + 1, ':30')`.

Comment: Hi @GMB, I'm just validating and if I do as you suggest, Hour 15 = 14:30 to 15:30 which is different to what you say. Is that correct?

Comment: @Philip: ah yes, you are correct, I thought the other way around. Just fixed my answer accordingly. So to display the time slot, you need `CONCAT([Hour] - 1, ':30-', [Hour], ':30')` instead.